# Python - Categorise a single value yields error "Input array must be 1 dimensional"

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am trying to categorise single float numbers avoiding a list of `if` and `elif` statements using `pd.cut`.

Why the 2 codes below yield error `Input array must be 1 dimensional`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.cut(0.96,bins=[0,0.5,1,10],labels=['A','B','C'])
pd.cut(np.array(0.96),bins=[0,0.95,1,10],labels=['A','B','C'])
```

Comment: `pd.cut([0.96],bins=[0,0.5,1,10],labels=['A','B','C'])`?

Comment: `pd.cut(np.array([0.96]),bins=[0,0.95,1,10],labels=['A','B','C'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) operates over an array-like object (as it states in the documentation for its first paramater: `x : array-like`). When you try to cut a single element, it's a 0-dimensional array. If you just say wrap `[]` around your `np.array` call, you'll get your desired result:

```
>>> pd.cut(np.array([0.96]),bins=[0,0.95,1,10],labels=['A','B','C'])
['B']
Categories (3, object): ['A' < 'B' < 'C']
```

When you do `np.array(0.96)`, it will return a 0-dimensional array containing that object, per the documentation for [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). You could also use the `ndmin` parameter to force Numpy to return a 1-dimensional array on your call: `np.array(0.96, ndmin=1) -> array([0.96])`.